# Update view from PFQuery objects as they are fetched

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a PFQuery that executes and then I update my view based on the results of the query. I'd like to update my view as the objects are fetched and not after they are all fetched.

I do not know how to attempt this after reading the PFQuery iOS class reference.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this function is possible using their standard SDK. From what I understand when parse sends a response for a query back to the client all the data is included together in one response.